# CSS changing colors in different browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser

I am experiencing a somewhat weird bug on a website I am building.

Using Chrome/Firefox/Safari/IE10 it works fine. However, using IE9 it turns into blue! What is wrong?

I suspect this code is messing it up (@colorOne, @colorTwo is replaced by the actual colors):

```
.gradient (@colorOne, @colorTwo) {
    background: @colorOne; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  @colorOne 0%, @colorTwo 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,@colorOne), color-stop(100%,@colorTwo)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  @colorOne 0%,@colorTwo 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  @colorOne 0%,@colorTwo 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  @colorOne 0%,@colorTwo 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  @colorOne 0%,@colorTwo 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@colorOne', endColorstr='@colorTwo',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a chunk of code ? We would like to know exactly what it's all about.

Comment: Is that "IE9" screenshot using a PC with the "Windows95" theme? ;-)

Comment: Are your colors rgba colors?  The gradient filter takes a different format for colors with transparency.

Comment: It's just from one of those render-from-different-browser websites :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a blue Microsoft filter gradient in your CSS on the `#top` element and other elements within your site. But since you're specifically asking about the header, just remove:

```css
#top {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@colorOne', endColorstr='@colorThree', GradientType=1);
  /* Remove this from any other element you wish to be green */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any clue why it doesn't even render in IE8?

Comment: Different filters support different versions of IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is a gradient only interpreted by IE:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@colorOne', endColorstr='@colorThree', GradientType=1
```

Simply remove it.